# row counter with condition in two different columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following tables with sport results (e.g. football):

> tblGoals (RowId, GameRowIdm PlayerRowId, TeamRowId, GoalMinute)

```
RowId | GameRowId | PlayerRowId | TeamRowId | GoalMinute
--------------------------------------------------------
1     | 1         | 1           | 1         | 25
2     | 1         | 2           | 2         | 45
3     | 1         | 3           | 1         | 66
```

> tblPlayers (RowId, PlayerName)

```
RowId | PlayerName
------------------
1     | John Snow
2     | Frank Underwood
3     | Jack Bauer
```

> tblGames (RowId, TeamHomeRowId, TeamGuestRowId)

```
RowId | TeamHomeRowId | TeamGuestRowId | GameDate
---------------------------------------------------
1     | 1             | 2              | 2015-01-01
```

Now I want get a list of all goals. The list should look like this:

```
GoalMinute | PlayerName      | GoalsHome | GoalsGuest
-----------------------------------------------------
25         | John Snow       | 1         | 0
45         | Frank Underwood | 1         | 1
66         | Jack Bauer      | 2         | 1
```

GoalsHome and GoalsGuest should be a counter of the shot goals for the team. So e.g. if you check the last row, the result is 2:1 for home team.
To get this list of goals, I used this statement:

```
SELECT  t_gol.GoalMinute,
        t_ply.PlayerName,
        CASE WHEN
            t_gol.TeamRowId = t_gam.TeamHomeRowId 
            THEN ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY t_gam.TeamHomeRowId ORDER BY t_gam.TeamHomeRowId)
        END AS GoalsHome,
        CASE WHEN
            t_gol.TeamRowId = t_gam.TeamGuestRowId 
            THEN ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY t_gam.TeamGuestRowId ORDER BY t_gam.TeamGuestRowId)
        END AS GoalsGuest
FROM    dbo.tblGoalsFussball AS t_gol
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblPlayersFussball AS t_ply ON (t_ply.RowId = t_gol.PlayerRowId)
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblGames AS t_gam ON (t_gam.RowId = t_gol.GameRowId)
WHERE   t_gol.GameRowId = @match_row
```

But what I get is this here:

```
GoalMinute | PlayerName      | GoalsHome | GoalsGuest
-----------------------------------------------------
25         | John Snow       | 1         | NULL
45         | Frank Underwood | NULL      | 2
66         | Jack Bauer      | 3         | NULL
```

Maybe ROW_NUMBER() is the wrong approach?

Comment: Some suggestions to improve your chances of getting a helpful answer:  a.) remove the first SELECT statement, and any reference to tblTeams and tblGames.  they are irrelevant to  your issue, and just make diagnosing it harder.   b.) in your second SELECT statement you refer to two tables tblGoalsFussball and tblPlayersFussball which you haven't mentioned anywhere else, so we don't know what data they contain.  3.) include some sample data from the tblGoals and tblPlayers tables (at least for the 3 players you've shown)

Comment: In your desired results, shouldn't the second row show 1:1 since there would have been 1 home goal and 1 guest goal at that point?

Comment: Yes, ur right, I edited my question. Sorry for that!

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the running total using `sum()` as a windowed aggregate function with the `over ...` clause, which works in SQL Server 2012+.

```
select 
    g.RowId, g.GameDate, t.GoalMinute, p.PlayerName, 
    GoalsHome = COALESCE(SUM(case when TeamRowId = g.TeamHomeRowId then 1 end) OVER (PARTITION BY gamerowid ORDER BY goalminute),0),
    GoalsGuest = COALESCE(SUM(case when TeamRowId = g.TeamGuestRowId then 1 end) OVER (PARTITION BY gamerowid ORDER BY goalminute),0) 
from tblGoals t
join tblPlayers p on t.PlayerRowId = p.RowId
join tblGames g on t.GameRowId = g.RowId
order by t.GameRowId, t.GoalMinute
```

Another approach (that also works in older versions) is to use a self-join and sum up the rows with lower goalminutes. For ease of reading I've used a common table expression to split the goals into two columns for home and guest team:

```
;with t as (
    select 
       g.GoalMinute, g.PlayerRowId, g.GameRowId, 
       case when TeamRowId = ga.TeamHomeRowId then 1 end HomeGoals,
       case when TeamRowId = ga.TeamGuestRowId then 1 end GuestGoals
    from tblGoals g
    join tblGames ga on g.GameRowId = ga.RowId
)

select 
    g.RowId, g.GameDate, t.GoalMinute, p.PlayerName, 
    GoalsHome  = (select sum(coalesce(HomeGoals,0)) from t t2 where t2.GoalMinute <= t.GoalMinute and t2.GameRowId = t.GameRowId),
    GoalsGuest = (select sum(coalesce(GuestGoals,0)) from t t2 where t2.GoalMinute <= t.GoalMinute and t2.GameRowId = t.GameRowId)
from t
join tblPlayers p on t.PlayerRowId = p.RowId
join tblGames g on t.GameRowId = g.RowId
order by t.GameRowId, t.GoalMinute
```

The CTE isn't necessary though, you could just as well use a derived table

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bd7789/3)

Comment: awesome, thx! The first part is the stuff I need. Second approach is a good example of "WITH".

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is with subqueries..

```
SELECT 
  tgs.GoalMinute,
  tpl.PlayerName,
  ( SELECT 
        COUNT(t.RowId) 
    FROM 
        tblgoals AS t 
    WHERE t.GoalMinute <= tgs.GoalMinute 
        AND t.GameRowId = tgm.RowId
        AND t.TeamRowId = tgm.TeamHomeRowId
  ) AS HomeGoals,
  ( SELECT 
        COUNT(t.RowId) 
    FROM 
        tblgoals AS t 
    WHERE t.GoalMinute <= tgs.GoalMinute 
        AND t.GameRowId = tgm.RowId
        AND t.TeamRowId = tgm.TeamGuestRowId
  ) AS GuestGoals
FROM 
     tblgoals AS tgs
     JOIN tblplayers AS tpl ON tgs.RowId = tpl.RowId
     JOIN tblGames AS tgm ON tgm.RowId = tgs.GameRowId
ORDER BY tgs.GoalMinute
```

Comment: sorry, no, it only counts 1 each row

Comment: if I understand your procedure,you I trying to get for every player how much goals he scored as a guest and how much as a host?? whats represent GoalsHome and what is GoalsHost??

Comment: No, GoalsHome and GoalsGuest means the total scored goals at this game minute. So the 3rd row should look like this: 66 | Jack Bauer | 2 | 1. I corrected my question, sry for this...

Comment: Look now on my answer, its edited....I think this is what you are looking for :) –